# vCard's tag in URI

Tags: ios, http, put, vcf-vcard

I need to upload Contact's information to the web server.  I know that it can be done using HTTP PUT approach.

Also API from *Address Book Programming guide*, even some wrappers (such as RHAddressBook), allow us to generate NSData from Person's contact information.

I detected by WireShark how it is done on one of the servers.

For instance the part of URI for creating (uploading) vCard is this:

```
.../default/17b0dff5-5145-4515-85c0-5eb56f225f12.vcf
```

How to generate that tag (17b0dff5-5145-4515-85c0-5eb56f225f12)?

How it is calculated from vCard's data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dont know which server you are going to interact with but, in general, the last segment of the URI just need to be unique in the addressbook collection on the server. That is why many clients use some form of [UUID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier).

In other words, the URI is not calculated from the vCard.

Comment: CARDDAV server. Yes, u right it should be unique. In case of reply WS returns eTag, that can be used for future detection of record changes..